# How do I send a file stream using Quart in Python?

Tags: python, quart

Following the example set in [Izmailoff's blog post](https://izmailoff.github.io/web/flask-file-streaming/), I was able to send remote files from Flask to the user, but when I switched to [Quart](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart), I started receiving a `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable` error.

The code is almost the exact same as on the blog, and I've tried using `await` to no avail, as it errored out with `object Response can't be used in 'await' expression`.

My code is as follows, with `raw_url` being the direct-access URL:

```py
req = requests.get(raw_url, stream=True)
return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type=req.headers['content-type'])
```

Comment: For more context, a stack trace can be found here: https://pastebin.com/pib4dkAy

Comment: I've found a workaround for now, but I'd be interested if someone has an explanation, or an answer to add to this. // Removing `stream_with_context()` and just leaving the response with the request content iterator seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> ```
> for data in iterable:  # type: ignore
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

is telling you that the `stream_with_context()` is not returning an object of type `iterable`. You can indeed inspect that by printing the output of that function and see what it returns.

My only guess would be that the values returned by the `iter_content()` of the `req` module may be different from the one on the blog

```
req.iter_content()
```

and hence the error. I am also inclined to think that this could also be caused by difference in `flask/python` versions.